# Set environment variables of development machine to docker container for nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, macos, unix

I'm trying to set environment variables of the development machine to a docker container that running a nodejs app.

The environment variable `mysql_address` of the development machine is

```
echo $mysql_address
192.168.1.10
```

The shell script for building docker container is

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker build -t myapp --build-arg MYSQL_ADDRESS=$mysql_address .
```

The Dockerfile is

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG MYSQL_ADDRESS

ENV mysql_address=$MYSQL_ADDRESS

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache npm
COPY package.json ./
COPY myApp.js ./
RUN npm install --omit=dev
CMD node /app/myapp.js
```

The code of the myapp.js is

```
console.log(process.env);
```

The command of running above container is

```
sudo docker run -d --name myapp myapp:latest
```

The result is

```
{
  ...
  mysql_address= '',
  ...
}
```

Why is the environment variable `mysql_address` inside the container empty?

I use `--build-arg` option inside the docker build command for receiving the environment variable of the development machine `mysql_address`, pass the variable using `ARG`, `ENV` to the docker container, and use the variable in `myapp.js` as showing above.

What is wrong?

The development machine is
MacOS v11.6.7

Comment: Is there another layer of `sudo` you haven't shown?  `sudo` resets its process's environment, so if you `sudo ./the_script` then the environment variable won't be set there.  That you're seeing the _name_ of the variable in `process.env` suggests that the Dockerfile `ENV` mechanic is working but it's not getting a value (I would not "bake in" a host name to an image this way though).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to remove `sudo` from the script, but the result did not change. I tried to `sudo echo $mysql_address`, the variable was displayed. Are there any other causes?